# Показать (реализацию) каждый 5 уровень

Tags: c#, unity3d

`Задача:` начиная с 27 уровня, каждый 5 раз, выводить некую реализацию, как такое реализовать ?

Получаю `GameManager.Instance.levelNumber` уровень, думал обойтись простым остатком от деления, но так как уровень с 27, и каждый 5 раз не всегда без остатка получается.

```
private void ShowingPurchases()
{
    if(GameManager.Instance.levelNumber >= 27) // начинаем с 27 уровня
    {
        currentCountLose++;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("CurrentCountLose", currentCountLose);
        Debug.Log ("<b> currentCountLose " +currentCountLose + "</b>");
        if (currentCountLose == 3) // каждый третий проигрыш
        {
            currentCountLose = 0;
            GameManager.Instance.isShowPurchases = true;
            Stream.TransitionToScene(GameManager.SCENE_LEVELS);
        } else  Show();

    } else  Show();
}
```

Comment: Простите, я немного запутался: в чем именно ваш вопрос? В заголовке (о поиске каждого 5го уровня после 27го) или, цитата, "если игрок проиграл 3 раза на уровень, выводить некую реализацию, как такое реализовать ?"?
В первом случае можно попробовать, как вы и писали, остатком отделения, но остаток искать для удобства можно от разности текущего уровня и "константы" 27.

Comment: Извините за непонятность, нужна реализация которая срабатывала бы каждый 5 уровень, начиная с 27 уровня

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По существу вопроса

```
    if(GameManager.Instance.levelNumber >= 27 && (GameManager.Instance.levelNumber - 27)%5 == 0)
    {...}
```

По таким условиям должно работать, если ничего не путаю...